# Task Does Not Contain a Definition for Where If Done in One Line of Code

Tags: c#, linq, async-await

Why does this work if I split the code into two lines:

```
List<Foo> foos = await _repo.GetFoos();
foos = foos.Where(x => x.FooType != FooType.A).ToList();
```

But doesn't work when I combine them and do the `Where` on the same line?

```
List<Foo> foos = await _repo.GetFoos().Where(x => x.FooType != FooType.A).ToList();
```

This produces an error:

> `Task<List<Foo>>` does not contain a definition for 'Where`...

Comment: Due to precedence rules, `await` applies to the result of all the calls. If that `_repo` is a generic repo on top of an ORM like EF or EF Core, you have a bigger issue. Check Gunnar Peipman's [No Need for Repository and Unit of Work with Entity Framework Core](https://gunnarpeipman.com/ef-core-repository-unit-of-work/). That `GetFoos` look like it loaded an entire table in memory before trying to filter it.

Comment: The entire table is not loaded into memory. The repo filters based on parameters that I left out of this example in order to keep it simple. Thanks!

Comment: "The entire table is not loaded into memory" so `GetFoos` does not return a `Task<List<...>>` ?

Comment: It does, but a sproc is called, from the repo method, that filters the results that are returned from the DB.

Comment: ah ok, so you simply apply a second in memory then

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 9):

You should use `await` like this:

```
List<Foo> foos = (await _repo.GetFoos()).Where(x => x.FooType != FooType.A).ToList();
```

That's because `.Where()` in `await _repo.GetFoos().Where()` is applied to `_repo.GetFoos()` not result of `await _repo.GetFoos()`.

Comment: That works, but why? Ah, because I'm doing `Where` on the result of `await` and not on the `_repo` call. Ahhhh. I missed that. Thanks!

Comment: That's because `.Where()` in `await _repo.GetFoos().Where()` is applyed to `_repo.GetFoos()` not result of `await _repo.GetFoos()`.

Comment: Actually, it IS the answer to my question and should definitely be included.

Comment: @BobHorn Yes, Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The `await` is applied to the object returned by the entire expression.

You are attempting to use `Enumerable.Where` on the `Task` returned by `_repo.GetFoos` which is invalid.

You could enclose the `await _repo.GetFoos()` in parentheses to force that to be evaluated first, then `Enumerable.Where` would be performed on the resultant `IEnumerable`.